# emacs not opening PDF files in external viewer

Tags: openwith

I have configured Emacs to open certain file types with external viewers:

```
(progn                                                                     
    (require 'openwith)                                                    
    (openwith-mode t)                                                      
    (setq openwith-associations '(("\\.pdf\\'" "evince" (file))))          
    (setq openwith-associations '(("\\.jpg\\'" "eog" (file))))             
   (setq openwith-associations '(("\\.png\\'" "eog" (file))))             
)
```

While `eog` file types are indeed opened with the `eog` program, when I navigate to a `PDF` file (with `C-x C-f`) this is what I see:

[image]

In contrast, when I navigate to `png` files they are opened in an external `eog` viewer as intended.

Comment: You are redefining `openwith-associations` three times in a row, each time differently -- the latest in time will prevail.  Instead, try defining it once in a list format that includes everything.  Here is a general example:  `(setq openwith-associations '(("\\.pdf\\'" "acroread" (file)) ("\\.mp3\\'" "xmms" (file)) ("\\.\\(?:mpe?g\\|avi\\|wmv\\)\\'" "mplayer" ("-idx" file)) ("\\.\\(?:jp?g\\|png\\)\\'" "display" (file))))`

Comment: @lawlist That would convert into a fine answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The original poster has defined `openwith-associations` three (3) times in a row, each time differently.  The latest in time will prevail.  Instead, consider using the following *list* format that includes everything:

```lisp
(setq openwith-associations '(
  ("\\.pdf\\'" "evince" (file))
  ("\\.\\(?:jp?g\\|png\\)\\'" "eog" (file))
  ("\\.mp3\\'" "xmms" (file))
  ("\\.\\(?:mpe?g\\|avi\\|wmv\\)\\'" "mplayer" ("-idx" file)) ))
```